# Automating startup tasks

Tags: linux, linux-mint, scripting

I have a "morning ritual" that occurs on every boot of my machine: starting up a few browser tabs, starting up skype, starting up terminator and subdividing some screens, etc.

Is there any tool that helps me script that, including auth and input (in the case of terminator)? I'm on Linux Mint.

Comment: What kind of "auth and input"? You can set up the various tabs or split panes of terminator easily enough and the tabs and skype as well. If you tell us what exactly you need to have in your terminators, I should be able to answer.

Comment: This is largely a [desktop environment](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Desktop_environment#Desktop_environments_for_the_X_Window_System) specific question, so you should say which DE you are using (Cinnamon, MATE, KDE...).

Comment: I'm using MATE. Regarding input, i mean scripting the button presses (CTRL+SHIFT+(Q|E)) when terminator launches, entering credentials in Skype/websites, etc.